# Find critical edges of an MST: possible with modified Prim's algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I came across this question while finding a solution for a "critical edge" problem. The original (C++) problem, which I have already solved, was:

> Consider a graph G=(V,E). Find how many edges belong to **all** MSTs, how many edges do **not** belong to **any** MST and how many edges belong to some MSTs, but not all.

Let's call "green", "red" and "yellow", respectively, the edges in the 3 above cases.

After conducting my research, I came across [Find all critical edges of an MST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720155/find-all-critical-edges-of-an-mst), which solves the problem. One would run a modified version of Kruskal's algorithm: if two or more edges of the same weight connect the same components, thus forming a cycle, then all these are yellow edges, i.e., edges that could be included in the MST (or not). Edges that have been indisputably selected are "green" and edges that create a cycle in the same component are "red". So, the original problem has been solved.

The issue with the above algorithm is that it runs in **O( |E| * log|V| )**, which is the running time of Kruskal's algorithm (please correct me if I'm wrong). I was considering whether a modified version of Prim's algortihm could also be used, as it has a better amortized complexity of **O( |E| + |V| log |V| )**, if a Fibonacci heap is used.

My feeling is that a modified version of Prim's algorithm cannot be used here, since we are obliged to iterate all edges based on ascending weight; however, I cannot prove this. So, it is possible to further reduce the complexity of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is easier than the problem of sensitivity analysis of minimum spanning trees, which is to determine how much each tree/nontree edge can increase/decrease in weight before the minimum spanning tree changes. The best known algorithm for MST sensitivity analysis appears to be due to [Seth Pettie (2005, arXived 2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1910), with a running time of O(|E| log alpha(|E|, |V|)). This is very close to optimal (alpha is inverse Ackermann) but also still superlinear. Several randomized algorithms with linear expected running times are known.